# Icon fonts: wrong sign displayed

Tags: html, css, icon-fonts

I created simple web page page with icon fonts.

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jkqsvdLt/)

Similar as here

[js trick](http://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/)

But I have other icon displayed...  snake instead of bars:).

What is wrong with my fonts? Thanks for answers.

Code here:

```
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: icons; /* BYO icon font, mapped smartly */
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none; /* Not to be trusted, but hey. */
}

<h4><span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#x21dd;"></span> Stats</h4>
```

Comment: Please post your code within the question itself. Bypassing StackOverflow's *JSFiddle links must be accompanied by code* warning by wrapping JSFiddle links in code tags is on par with breaking the rules of the site.

Comment: _The icon font used on this page is [Fico](http://fico.lensco.be/) by Lennart Schoors then ran through [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/#home) for custom mappings._

Comment: Question has been fixed, please  mark it as correct question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x21dd; is the unicode that represents that "snake".

[Source](http://www.codetable.net/hex/21dd)

Try to use [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons (I included them in the CSS by using the @font-face).

All you need to do is to define a class in a tag like

```
<b class="fa fa-chart"></b>
```

And FontAwesome will automatically add the icon inside that tag.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wh386wq1/).

Comment: Yes, I need specially prepared fonts to see 'columns'. 'Snake' is good sign for defualt fonts.